# How can I censor any words from a textarea that are between quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a text censor web app, which would censor any words from a textarea which are between quotation marks. E.g The dog is "red" = The dog is "XXX", The dog is "quite big" = The dog is "XXXXX XXX".

I currently have it set so that any word from a key list of words ( currently red ) gets censored, but would like to change it to any word between quotations (" ") becomes censored.

I am using HTML, JS and some CSS, but I have tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work, I keep getting js errors in the console.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('formSub');

function censorWords(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var textContent = document.getElementById('input');
    //List of key words to censor
    var redacted = ["red"];
    console.log(textContent.value)
    textContent.value = censored(textContent.value, redacted);
}

function censored(string, filters) {
    console.log('in')
    // "i" ignores case, "g" for global and "|" for OR match
    var regexp = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
    return string.replace(regexp, function (match) {
        //this is where the words are replaced with X
        var censorship = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
            censorship += 'X';
        }
        return censorship
    })
}

div.addEventListener('click', censorWords)
```

```css
html {
    background-color: rgb(42, 44, 53) ;
    
}

body h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 1%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

body p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 6%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

.inputform {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20%;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(56, 59, 70) ;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    .inputform {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 30%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 20%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document Censor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Text Censor</h1>
    <p>This text censor will remove any key words, and replace them with 'X's. To begin, input text into box
        press 'Censor Text', and your censored text is ready to go!
    </p>
    <form class="inputform" name="redacted" method="post" action="">
        <textarea id="input" name="text"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Censor Text" />
    </form>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there going to be words with `"` in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple version of `censored`:

```js
const censored = (w) => 
    w .replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, (_, s) => `"${s.replace(/\S/g, 'X')}"`)
```

We find all text between two quotation marks, replace it by replacing all its non-space characters with `'X'`, and return the new value.  It wouldn't work with nested quotes, but that would be strange to support anyway.

We can see it in action in this snippet:

```js
const censorWords = (event) => {
  event .preventDefault ()
  var textContent = document .getElementById ('input')
  textContent .value = censored (textContent .value)
}

const censored = (w) => 
  w .replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, (_, s) => `"${s.replace(/\S/g, 'X')}"`)

document.getElementById('formSub') .addEventListener ('click', censorWords)
```

```css
html {background-color: rgb(42, 44, 53);}
.inputform {position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
textarea {display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: .2em; width: auto; min-width: 80%; height: auto; min-height: 20%; cursor: text; background-color: #eee; overflow: auto; resize: both; border: 3px solid #ffffff; background-color: rgb(56, 59, 70); color: #ffffff;}
```

```html
<form class="inputform" name="redacted" method="post" action="">
  <textarea id="input" name="text">Add text here with "words you want to censor" contained in "quotes".  Then press the button.</textarea>
  <br />
  <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Censor Text" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Going more advanced, is there anyway it can leave punctuation and only censor letters?

Comment: Sure, instead of `{s.replace(/\S/g, 'X')`, which says to replace all non-spaces with `'X'`, you can do `s.replace(/[a-z]/ig, 'X')`, which says to replace all letters with `'X'`.  If you wanted to hide letters and numbers, it's even simpler: `{s.replace(/\w/g, 'X')`, which replaces "word" characters, that is, letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are not going to be words with " in them, you can use `split` function.

```js
var sentence = 'The dog is "red" = The dog is "quite big sir"'
console.log(sentence)

function censor_word(word) {
  return word.replace(/\S/g, "*");
}

var arr = sentence.split('"');
if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
  console.error("Illegal double quotes in message")
}

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  var to_censor = arr[i];
  var censored = censor_word(to_censor);
  arr[i] = censored;
}

var result = arr.join('"')
console.log(result)

// or in one line
var result2 = sentence.split('"').map((element, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? element : element.replace(/\S/g, "*")).join('"')
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: this works fine for the defined sentence, but whenever I change the 'var sentence = document.getElementById('input')', to link with the textarea input, it doesnt work.

Comment: try `var sentence = document.getElementById('input').innerText`

Comment: got a http error 405. Maybe something with the html, like the input button or something?

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array by quotes, and replace every odd word.

```
const testString = 'The quick "brown" fox ate his lunch';

function removeWordsInQuotes(string) {

        let wordArray = string.split('"');

        for (let index = 0; index < wordArray.length; index++) {
                const element = wordArray[index];
                if (index % 2 === 1) {

                    //this is where the words are replaced with X
                        let censorship = '';
                        for (let j = 0; j < element.length; j++) {
                                censorship += 'X';
                        }
                        wordArray[index] = censorship;
                }
        }
        return wordArray.join('"');
}

console.log(removeWordsInQuotes(testString)); // "The quick 'XXXXX' fox ate his lunch"
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/andreasaanestad/pen/PoRoOQz)

Comment: I tried to link this with html text area and input button, by changing the ‘test string = document.getElementById('input')', and it didn’t work.

Comment: You would have to do document.getElementById('input').value